Using React TS, typewriter effect not working
So I created a typewriter effect for writing text, then deleted it infinitely.
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const Typewriter = ({ text, customColor }) => {
  const [output, setOutput] = useState('');
  const stepRef = useRef(0);
  const shouldDeleteRef = useRef(false);
  console.log("Typing:", text);

  useEffect(() => {
    const typeWriter = async (text) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        console.log("Adding character:", text.charAt(i)); 
        setOutput(text.substring(0, i + 1)); 
        await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 100));
      }
      await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 1000));

      for (let i = text.length; i > 0; i--) {
        console.log("Deleting character:", text.charAt(i - 1)); 
        setOutput(text.substring(0, i - 1)); 
        await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 100));
      }

      await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 1000));

      typeWriter(text);
    };

    typeWriter(text);
  }, [text]);

  const cursorStyle = {
    display: 'inline-block',
    width: '0.1em',
    height: '1em',
    marginLeft: '0.25em',
    backgroundColor: customColor || 'white',
    animation: 'blink 1s infinite',
  };

  return (
    <span style={{ color: customColor, fontFamily: 'monospace' }}>
      {output}
      <span style={cursorStyle}></span>
    </span>
  );
};
export default Typewriter;

This is the closest I have gotten it to work, it just stands at the blinking cursor though, unsure why, and in logs it only says "Typing: example" never logging anything else. I can't tell if I'm being stupid; I have not done much web development in the past, and I am pretty tired at the moment.

This seems to be working fine... i can see the text i provided "My text" to have this typewrite effect. The text is displayed on scree character by character and once it fully displays the text, then it deletes it character by character
